# n-volume of a n-dimensional convex polyhedron

Tags: python-2.7, area, convex-hull

I wish to find n-volume of an n-dimensional convex polytope (Area for a 2D polytope, volume for a 3D polytope etc). Is there a "generalized" formula  (or algorithm) which can be written in python (or even a python package)?

Edit - 1:
To answer norok2's comment, the polytope is defined as set of ordered vertices.

Comment: How is your polytope defined?

Comment: The polytope is defined as a set of ordered vertices.

Comment: One way of doing this would be find the delimiting hyperplanes in (dis)equation form and then generate random samples of the hypercube containing the polytope and classify each sample as in or out the polytope, the in/out ratio times the hypercube volume will give you a good approximation of the volume.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. But, in my application, exact area is required.

Comment: Quickly searching for `monte carlo volume computation` gives, e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050911002092

Comment: review of exact methods: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.42.7953&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

Using the Python package [`polytope`](https://github.com/tulip-control/polytope), a polytope's volume can be computed as follows:

```py
"""How to compute a polytope's volume."""
import numpy as np
import polytope

# constructing a convex polytope and computing its volume
vertices = np.array([[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
hull = polytope.qhull(vertices)
    # `hull` is an instance of the class `polytope.polytope.Polytope`
    # which is for representing a convex polytope
print(hull.volume)

# constructing a nonconvex polytope and computing its volume
vertices_1 = np.array([[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [2.0, 1.0]])
vertices_2 = np.array([[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [0.0, 2.0]])
hull_1 = polytope.qhull(vertices_1)  # convex hull of vertices in `vertices_1`
hull_2 = polytope.qhull(vertices_2)  # convex hull of vertices in `vertices_2`
nonconvex = hull_1.union(hull_2)  # construct union of convex polytopes
    # `nonconvex` is an instance of the class `polytope.polytope.Region`
    # which is for representing any polytope, including nonconvex ones,
    # and in this case can also be constructed with
    # `polytope.polytope.Region([hull_1, hull_2])`
print(nonconvex.volume)
```

The package `polytope` computes volume using a randomized algorithm, implemented in the function [`polytope.polytope.volume`](https://github.com/tulip-control/polytope/blob/f981f434a270ee005076b9c534383aeaba314f40/polytope/polytope.py#L1435-L1477). The above code also uses the classes [`numpy.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), [`polytope.polytope.Polytope`](https://github.com/tulip-control/polytope/blob/f981f434a270ee005076b9c534383aeaba314f40/polytope/polytope.py#L95-L115), [`polytope.polytope.Region`](https://github.com/tulip-control/polytope/blob/f981f434a270ee005076b9c534383aeaba314f40/polytope/polytope.py#L615-L633), and the functions [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), [`polytope.polytope.qhull`](https://github.com/tulip-control/polytope/blob/f981f434a270ee005076b9c534383aeaba314f40/polytope/polytope.py#L1567-L1573), and (indirectly) [`polytope.polytope.union`](https://github.com/tulip-control/polytope/blob/f981f434a270ee005076b9c534383aeaba314f40/polytope/polytope.py#L1109-L1117).

The above Python code is with `polytope` version 0.2.3.

The package `polytope` can be installed from [PyPI](https://pypi.org) using [`pip`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/):

```sh
pip install polytope
```